# jqGrid: Performance issues and pager not working properly while updating data from second page

Tags: php, jquery, sql, performance, jqgrid

Question 1: I have table containing 999 rows with a primary key. I am using jqGrid to show these data. It is taking some extra time to load data. Is there any way to resolve it.

Question 2: I am editing a row from the second page of the grid. It is updating data just fine with one problem. It is updating the row of second page and reloading grid and going to first page without updating page number in the navbar. I mean pager is showing 'page 2 of 100' instead of 'page 1 of 100'. Is there any way to update data without reloading grid to first page? I want data to be updated just fine and showing the current page.

**Following are the description with image : **

**1. Initial loading taking extra time:
[image]

**2. After loading all data: 
[image]

**3. Editing 12th row in 2nd page:
[image]

**4. After editing, loaded data are of 1st page "001 to 009", but pager shows "2 of 10"
[image]

**My CODE are as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, { altRows:true });
        $("#list_records").jqGrid({
            url: 'ajaxELearningFetchTableData.php?table=GET_TRAINING_TYPE',
            //url: 'server.php',
            editurl: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ["TRAINING TYPE ID", "TRAINING TYPE NAME", "REMARKS", "ACTIONS"],
            colModel: [
                {
                    label: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                    name: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                    index: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                    editable:true,
                    sortable:true,
                    sorttype: "text",
                    editoptions:{readonly:"readonly"},
                    //width: 75                        
                },
                {
                    label : 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                    name: 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                    index: 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                    //width: 140,
                    editable: true, // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable
                    editoptions: {size:50, maxlength: 80},
                    editrules:{required: true, maxlength: 80},
                    sortable:true,
                    sorttype: "text",
                    // set options related to the layout of the Edit and Add Forms
                    formoptions: {
                        colpos: 1, // the position of the column
                        rowpos: 2, // the position of the row
                        label: "Training Type Name:", // the label to show for each input control  
                        elmsuffix: "(*)"                 

                    }
                },
                {
                    label : 'Remarks',
                    name: 'REMARKS',
                    //width: 100,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'textarea',
                    editoptions:{rows:3, cols:45},
                    formoptions: {
                        colpos: 1,
                        rowpos: 3
                    }
                },
                { name: "act", 
                    formatter: "actions", 
                    editbutton:true,
                    delbutton:true,
                    formatoptions: { 
                        editformbutton: true,
                        editOptions : {
                            closeOnEscape:true,
                            closeAfterEdit:true,
                            recreateForm: true,
                            width:620,
                            url: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
                            afterSubmit: function () {
                                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                    return [true];

                            },
                            afterComplete:function(response, postdata, formid){

                                console.log(response.responseText);
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }

                        },

                        delOptions : {
                            closeOnEscape:true,
                            recreateForm: true,
                            width:620,
                            url: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
                            onclickSubmit: function () {

                                var sel_id = $('#list_records').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');                       
                                var trainingTypeId = $('#list_records').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID');
                                //alert(trainingTypeId);
                                return { tTypeId: trainingTypeId };                             

                            },

                            afterSubmit: function () {
                                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                    return [true];

                            },
                            afterComplete:function(response, postdata, formid){
                                console.log(response.responseText);
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }

                        }

                    },

                    width: 54, 
                    align: "center", 
                    fixed: true, 
                    hidedlg: true, 
                    resizable: false,
                    sortable: false, 
                    search: false, 
                    editable: false, 
                    viewable: false  
                }
            ],
            loadonce : true,
            viewrecords: true,
            altRows: true,
            width: 780,
            height: 200,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList:[10, 20, 30],
            caption:"Training Type Information",
            sortname: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            emptyrecords: "No Records to Display.",
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                $(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid);
            },
            //footerrow: true,
            pager: "#perpage"
        });

        $('#list_records').navGrid('#perpage',
            // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
            { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false },
            // options for the Edit Dialog
            {
                height: 'auto',
                width: 620,
                editCaption: "Edit Training Type",
                url: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
                recreateForm: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                afterComplete:function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                afterSubmit: function () {
                    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                        return [true];
                    //location.reload(true);
                }
            },
            // options for the Add Dialog
            {
                height: 'auto',
                width: 620,
                addCaption: "Add Training Type",
                url: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                afterComplete:function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                afterSubmit: function () {
                    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                        return [true];
                    //location.reload(true);
                }
            },
            // options for the Delete Dailog
            {
                height: 'auto',
                width: 620,
                addCaption: "Delete Training Type",
                url: 'ajaxELearningSaveTrainingType.php',
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                //rp_ge, postdata
                onclickSubmit: function () {

                    var sel_id = $('#list_records').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');                       
                    var trainingTypeId = $('#list_records').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID');
                    return { tTypeId: trainingTypeId };


                },
                afterComplete:function(response){
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                afterSubmit: function () {
                    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                        return [true];
                    //location.reload(true);
                }
            });
    });
```

**Any help will be welcomed cordially.

Comment: You should **always** include the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the fork of jqGrid. If you use old version of jqGrid then you should use `gridview: true` option to improve the performance (free jqGrid has it as default). You should include the test JSON data returned from the server (at least 2 rows of data). Contains  `TRAINING_TYPE_ID` unique key of the data? By the way, the code, which you posted can be reduced in about two times.

Comment: Bugs, like showing wrong page number, will be fixed only in **the current version** of jqGrid. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork and can implement the bug fix in the fork. To test it you need just change 3-4 lines of your code to load free jqGrid files from CDN or RawGit (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). If you use commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), then you should post bug report to the corresponding [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js)